# Compute the hash of only the core image data of a TIFF

Tags: python, tiff

Using Python, how can I compute the md5 hash of a TIFF image, excluding all metadata?

With a JPG, I do something like this:

```
def jpeg(fh):
  hash = hashlib.md5()
  assert fh.read(2) == "\xff\xd8"
  while True:
      marker,length = struct.unpack(">2H", fh.read(4))
      assert marker & 0xff00 == 0xff00
      if marker == 0xFFDA: # Start of stream
          hash.update(fh.read())
          break
      else:
          fh.seek(length-2, os.SEEK_CUR)
  print "Hash: %r" % hash.hexdigest()

>> jpeg(file("test.jpg"))
>> Hash: 'debb4956941795d6ef48717e4c9cc433'
```

Not sure how to extend this to TIFF images.

It seems trickier with TIFFs because the location of the metadata within the image can change (it's not always at the beginning or end).

Comment: Seems like it'd be better to hash the image data instead, e.g. by opening the file using PIL and hashing the image's tostring.

Comment: You can strip the metadata using exiftool: http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/   There is also python wrapper http://smarnach.github.com/pyexiftool/

Comment: @TJD From my usage, it seems that Exiftool doesn't properly strip exif tags from TIFF images. Works well for JPGs

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Image](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) module from the Python Imaging Library. The `tostring` method of the `Image` class returns the pixel data as a string.

```
import Image # Python Imaging Library
import hashlib

def hashtiff(fn):
    tf = Image.open(fn)
    return hashlib.md5(tf.tostring()).hexdigest()
```

MD5 has [known weaknesses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) as a hash algorithm. It is [considered](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/secure_hashing.html) [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549988/whats-the-recommended-hashing-algorithm-to-use-for-stored-passwords) to use e.g. SHA-256 or SHA-512.